# Regex for consecutive characters in string

Tags: python, regex

I have a string as below:

```
void func( str **s1, int *i, str *s2)
```

I want to write a regex which will find the occurence of `str` followed by number of `*` characters and put them in brackets like below:

```
void func( (str **) s1, int *i, (str *) s2)
```

Comment: Show us what you have already tried.

Answer (score 3):

This should work for the given example:

```
s = 'void func( str **s1, int *i, str *s2)'
print re.sub(r'\b(str\s+[*]+)', r'(\1) ', s)
```

*Gives:*

```
void func( (str **) s1, int *i, (str *) s2)
```

To substitute `str` with arbitrary strings:

```
items = ['str1', 'str2']
print re.sub(r'\bstr\s+([*]+)', 
    lambda x: r'({} {}) '.format(items.pop(0), x.group(1)), s)
```

to get:

```
void func( (str1 **) s1, int *i, (str2 *) s2)
```

Comment: What if items contains items = ['char', 'int']

Comment: did you try the above with that kind of list?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59157/discussion-between-pratibha-and-perreal).

Answer (score 0):

```
 x="void func( str **s1, int *i, str *s2)"   
 print re.sub(r"(str) ([^a-zA-Z0-9]+)",r"(\1 \2) ",x)
```

This works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following regex replacement:

```
re.sub(r'str\W+', r'(\0) ', str)
```

This is a shorter and more effective regex.

[View a regex demo!](http://regex101.com/r/yY9oV2/2)

```
>>> import re
>>> str ="void func( str **s1, int *i, str *s2)"
>>> e = re.sub(r'str\W+', r'(\0) ', str)
>>> e
'void func( (str **) s1, int *i, (str *) s2)'
```